# Coded UI Test: ApplicationUnderTest close after test complete

Tags: c#, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have seen lot of answered for same question on stakeoverflow but nothing is working for me.

I am using Visual studio 2013. I have a very simple Test

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{
     static ApplicationUnderTest _application;
    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        var mainWindow = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe");
        mainWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
        _application = mainWindow;                 
    }
}
```

I am setting  CloseOnPlaybackCleanup to false as mentioned below.

```
 mainWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
```

But whenever i run/debug test, application get close after test is completed. I have noticed that for browser window if we set CloseOnPlaybackCleanup to false then it work fine and browser window do not close. I am expecting same behavior for my this test.

can anyone please help me to identify if anything is missing?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Replace launching code with below line:

`var mainWindow = Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe");`

this should not close your application.